# Weird "border" with jpegtran when rotating an image

Tags: libjpeg-turbo, jpegtran

I'm using **jpegtran** to rotate my images, but it seems to be doing some weird stuff.
The same code/logic worked on my other server. Here is a test case I've done:

test.jpg is the original image, then I run:

```
jpegtran -rotate 90 test1.jpg > test2.jpg.tmp
mv test2.jpg.tmp test2.jpg
jpegtran -rotate 90 test2.jpg > test3.jpg.tmp
mv test3.jpg.tmp test3.jpg
```

**test.jpg:**

[image: test1.jpg]

**test2.jpg**

[image: test2.jpg (first rotation)]

**test3.jpg:**

[image: test3.jpg (2nd rotation)]

As you should be able to see, there are weird borders on it (almost like shadows on another part of the image):

[image]

What would cause this, and how can I get around it?

The **OLD** server shows:

```
jpegtran -v
libjpeg-turbo version 1.2.1 (build 20131209)
Copyright (C) 1991-2010 Thomas G. Lane, Guido Vollbeding
Copyright (C) 1999-2006 MIYASAKA Masaru
Copyright (C) 2009 Pierre Ossman for Cendio AB
Copyright (C) 2009-2012 D. R. Commander
Copyright (C) 2009-2011 Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies)

Emulating The Independent JPEG Group's libjpeg, version 6b  27-Mar-1998
```

...and the **NEW** server shows:

```
jpegtran -v
Independent JPEG Group's JPEGTRAN, version 9b  17-Jan-2016
Copyright (C) 2016, Thomas G. Lane, Guido Vollbeding
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, no sooner had I written the question out and posted it, I found the solution :)

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=21341#p87099

Basically, to add "-trim" to the command - so it looks like:

```
jpegtran -rotate 90 -trim test1.jpg > test2.jpg.tmp
mv test2.jpg.tmp test2.jpg
jpegtran -rotate 90 -trim test2.jpg > test3.jpg.tmp
mv test3.jpg.tmp test3.jpg
```

I've just tried this out, and it works as expected :) Thought I would post it here in case anyone else comes across this!